Loading Webpack bundle module with SystemJS
I have a UMD module, that i created using Webpack with  the config "libraryTarget: 'umd’”.
So the module starts with:
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) { 
  if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object') module.exports = factory(); 
  else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) define([], factory); 
  else { var a = factory(); for(var i in a) (typeof exports === 'object' ? exports : root)[i] = a[i]; } 
})

I’m trying to load my module with a CDN link on a script tag at the client website:
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://my-cdn-link/my-module.min.js';
script.onload = function() {
  if (window.moduleParam) {
    console.log("working");
  }
};
document.head.appendChild(script);

The client is using SystemJS imports:
<script src=“/.../systemjs@6.8.3/dist/system.min.js"></script>
<script src="/.../systemjs@6.8.3/dist/extras/amd.min.js"></script>

But it doesn’t work, and there is no error msg.
Only if I’m setting define.amd=null it’s working (using the global load).
What am I missing? the client have SystemJS AMD loader (define), my module is UMD which support AMD loading as well.
The only thing that i found is this - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8833
